# Why substitution in $\arctan(x)$ taylor expansion for $\arctan(1/z)$ doesn't work .

Tags: calculus

The Taylor series of $\sin\left(x\right)$ about zero

$$ \sin\left(x\right)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$$

so if I want $\sin\left(2x\right)$ about zero
$$ \sin\left(2x\right)=2x-\frac{\left(2x\right)^3}{3!}+\frac{\left(2x\right)^5}{5!}+\cdots$$

simple plugging now 
I want to expand $\arctan\left(x\right)$ about infinity so a little trick I evaluate $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)  $ about zero
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2} $$ so clearly our zeroth term must be $\frac{\pi}{2}  $
I will add the zeroth term and just do plugging as before 
$$\arctan\left(z\right)=z-\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^5}{5}+\cdots$$
So adding the zeroth term and "plugging"
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{5x^5}+\cdots$$
Unfortunately this is wrong the true result is
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3}-\frac{1}{5x^5}+\cdots$$
using identity $ \arctan\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(z\right)$

My question why in this particular case plugging and substitution into known Taylor expansion didn't work as in the $\left(x\right)$ case ?
I have been doing this safely and finding a counter example seems to be dangerous , sorry for being lengthy .

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} arctan(\frac{1}{x}) =\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not correct. The limit is $0$.

Comment: Sorry I meant $ \lim_{x \to 0} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2} $

I have edited it .

Answer (score 1):

The last equation $\arctan(\tfrac 1z)=\tfrac π2−\arctan(z)$ is correct, so for $|z|>1$
$$
\arctan(z)=\frac π2-\arctan\left(\frac 1z\right)=\frac π2-\frac 1z+\frac1{3z^3}-\frac1{5z^5}\pm...
$$
Note that the Taylor series for the arcus tangens only has a radius of convergence of $1$.

Comment: Where is my mistake in Just substituting $\frac{1}{z}$ for z ?

Comment: That you did not do it? Then it would have been simply $$\arctan\left(\frac1z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)z^{2k+1}}$$ without any shift in the constant coefficient and of course for $|z|>1$.

Comment: That is my Question what the difference between Yours and this clearly

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3}.........$$